# Is there anyway to stop CKEditor 4 from filtering my anchor tag attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg

CKEditor 4 attribute filtering is stripping any occurrence "href" from anchor tags put into the editor. I have a plugin which creates links that contain some "custom" attributes. A link looks something like this:

```
<a href="#" document-href="abc123">Some Link</a>
```

The CKEditor returns the link in this form when I call getData():

```
<a href="#" document->Some Link</a>
```

Is there a way to instruct CKEditor to stop filtering link attributes? Does anyone happen to know where in the source this regex is so I can fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just checked this link on CKEditor 4.1 - the output is:

```
<p><a href="#">Some Link</a></p>
```

Since 4.1 the `document-href` is stripped because it is now allowed in the editor. You have to add an [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) rule - e.g.:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'a[!href,document-href]';
```

And then it would work in 4.1. Before 4.1 it should work by default, without setting anything.

**However** there's a bug in CKEditor's HTML parser. It does not parse correctly `sth-href` attributes on links so a result is a `sth-` attribute.

For now I advice you to change the name of this attribute to `data-url` or whatever else without `href` ending.

I created a ticket: https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10298

Comment: Thanks for creating the ticket. I was going to do that after I found the responsible piece of code. The workaround will do for now. I am just rewriting the link on the way into the editor and rewriting them when I retrieve them out from the editor.

Answer (score 2):

try setting this in config file.

```
    config.allowedContent = true;
```

also if its getting filtered on insert then you can try this:

```
//var yourAnchor = '<a href="#" document-href="abc123">Some Link</a>';

editor.insertHtml(yourAnchor, 'unfiltered_html');
```

Comment: Thanks. It didn't make a difference.

Comment: try passing 'unfiltered_html' in the mode for your insert.
editor.insertHtml(yourAnchor, 'unfiltered_html');

Comment: Setting `allowedContent = true;` removes ALL filtering, which is one of the main reasons one would use CKEditor. You'll create more issues than you fix by doing this instead of configuring it correctly. So, while it may resolve OP's issue, it isn't recommended.