# Stop CKEditor from cleaning custom attributes

Tags: html, drupal, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm using Drupal 7 with CKEditor 4.2 and want to allow certain custom content. So I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795142/is-there-anyway-to-stop-ckeditor-4-from-filtering-my-anchor-tag-attributes) and added the following config to sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor/config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
  ...
  config.extraAllowedContent = 'pre (!command-line); span (!command); span(!comment); span(!output); em';
};
```

Still, content such as the following which I enter through CKEditor in plain-text mode is cleaned/removed:

```
<pre class="command-line">
    <span class="command"> ... <em>...</em></span>
    <span class="comment">...</span>
    <span class="output">...</span>
</pre>
```

I also tried using allowedContent instead of extraAllowedContent without any effect. In either case the format is cleaned. Maybe my configuration is being ignored by CKEditor or it's wrong in itself?

Comment: [Your rules are OK](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/XnFLK/). But `span.comment` and `span.output` will be stripped out as you configured that every `<span>` got to have `.command` class or it's out. Maybe there's something wrong with your config?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I corrected the rule for "span" elements. Still the issue remains valid.

Comment: I've just checked your code in basic CKEditor sample and it works - all classes and elements are correctly preserved. I think that either you haven't cleaned your cache or your config file is not loaded.